# Java: Replace multiple strings in a file and write it to a output file

Tags: java

I have a input file inputfile.txt with follwoing 3 lines:

```
REPLACE_STRING_1 is karthik
REPLACE_STRING_2 is 21
REPLACE_STRING_3 is chennai
```

I need to replace the replace_strings with different values and write the contents to a new file. But with the below code, I end up having 3 sets of same lines in the new file. How can I fix this? I want the final output to look like this:

```
name is karthik
age is 21
city is chennai
```

Here is my code:

```
try {
    File file = new File("inputfile.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = "", oldtext = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        oldtext += line + "\r\n";
    }
    reader.close();

    String ReplaceVar1 = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_1", "name");                
    String ReplaceVar2 = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_2", "age");
    String ReplaceVar3 = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_3", "city");

    // Write updated record to a file
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("outputfile.txt");
    writer.write(ReplaceVar1 + ReplaceVar2 + ReplaceVar3);                
    writer.close();                
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `String ReplaceVar1 = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_1", "name"); String ReplaceVar2 = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_2", "age"); String ReplaceVar3 = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_3", "city");`

Comment: You should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you write a line comment describing the following couple of lines, you should find a good title for this description and put the whole thing in a new method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the new text and print only the last result.

```
String result = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_1", "name")
                       .replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_2", "age")
                       .replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_3", "city");
```

Note that `String` is immutable and `replaceAll` returns the whole text, with the desired change.

Comment: thank you. I've edited the code... as you said that was a typo while I tried to post a generic code on this forum removing parts that are not needed here. I am not sure why I got the down votes.

Comment: @Karthik I've changed the answer too.

Comment: @Elazar This fixed it! Thanks a lot for the help and for the clarification on String!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    File file = new File("inputfile.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = "", oldtext = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        oldtext += line + "\r\n";
    }
    reader.close();


    System.out.println("Running ReplaceText");
    // replace a word in a file
    // REPLACE_STRING_1TENANT_ID REPLACE_STRING_1SOURCE_IP REPLACE_STRING_1USER_NAME REPLACE_STRING_1TARGET_HOSTNAME REPLACE_STRING_1MBODY_TIME
    String newText = oldtext.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_1", "name");                
    newText = newText.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_2", "age");
    newText = newText.replaceAll("REPLACE_STRING_3", "city");

    // Write updated record to a file
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("outputfile.txt");
    writer.write(newText);                
    writer.close();                
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tested this it giving me the proper output

```
-MacBook-Pro-2:Desktop john$ cat outputfile.txt 
name is karthik
age is 21
city is chennai
```